# Switch Statements and Modulo

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, modulo

Hi I'm a bit confused as to why I am not getting anything logged in this function. If I pass 10 through the function shouldn't 'case2' be logged? I think it has something to do with the way I wrote the modulo line...

```
 function helloWorld(num) {
        switch (num){
                case num % 3 === 0:
                    console.log('case1');
                    break

                case num % 5 === 0:
                     console.log('case2');
                     break

                case num % 3 === 0 && num % 5 ===0:
                     console.log('case3');
                     break
            }
        }

 helloWorld(10);
```

Comment: Do not abuse a `switch` statement, just use an `if`/`else` cascade if that's what you want. Use `switch` statements only with constants in the `case`s.

Comment: "*why I am not getting anything logged*" - because the boolean expressions in your cases never match the `num` that you are `switch`ing on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `case` statement is intended to be used comparing a value to the one specified in the `switch` statement.

You are adding a boolean condition inside each `case`, forcing unexpected behaviour. What you have done is formally correct, but is semantically incorrect.

This is the correct code:

```js
 function helloWorld(num) {
   if((num % 3) === 0)
     console.log('case1');

   else if((num % 5) === 0)
     console.log('case2');

   else if((num % 3) === 0 && (num % 5) === 0)
     console.log('case3');
 }

helloWorld(10);
```

For more information on the `switch` statement:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch